# How do i sum the Inputs for each value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I would like to have the sum of the values of each checked checkbox input.
I tried my best and have problems with the following code:

```
$("#timediff").on("keyup", function() {

    var v_id = Number("0"); 

    $("input:checked").each(function () { 
      v_id = Number(v_id) +Number($("input:checked").val());

    alert(v_id);
    });

    var s_id = $("#timediff").val();

    if (s_id<=v_id) {
       alert('The"' + s_id +' h" are smaller than "' + v_id + 'h"');
    }else{
          alert('The"' + s_id +' h" are bigger than "' + v_id + 'h"');
    }
  });
```

My output is always the sum of the repeated value of the first `"checked"` checkbox.

For example, `Checkbox1: Value="5", Checkbox2: Value="2", Checkbox3: Value="1"`. 
The output is 15.
But I would like to have 8 as the result. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Isn't `$("input:checked")` an array? When you are looping get each checked element and invoke `.val()` on each element.

Comment: $(this).val() was the answer i was looking for ! Maybe you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("input:checked").val()
```

to this:

```
$(this).val()
```

And don't forget to convert `s_id` to a number before the `<=` comparison.